# Reading from Vision API Text Detection and Filling Appropriate fields

Tags: javascript, html, ocr, vision

Have been trying to read data out of an Govt. Issued identity card and fill the fields of the form like following using google's Vision Api..

[image: Government ID]

I've successfully read the data from the vision API but now facing problems filling the form like following with appropriate data..

[image: Form]

How can i achieve this?

[image: What i Wish to get]

The response from Vision API:

```
{
"responses": [
    {
        "textAnnotations": [
            {
                "locale": "en",
                "description": "amagas faATST\nINCOME TAX DEPARTMENT\nMAHENDRAKUMARRBAGUL\nRAMKRISHNA NATTHU BAGUL\n01/06/1981\n4Permanent Account Number\nANSAB4834E\nSignature\nGOVT OF INDIA\n",
                "boundingPoly": {
                    "vertices": [
                        {
                            "x": 2,
                            "y": 64
                        },
                        {
                            "x": 4308,
                            "y": 64
                        },
                        {
                            "x": 4308,
                            "y": 2701
                        },
                        {
                            "x": 2,
                            "y": 2701
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "description": "amagas",
                "boundingPoly": {
                    "vertices": [
                        {
                            "x": 6,
                            "y": 64
                        },
                        {
                            "x": 774,
                            "y": 65
                        },
                        {
                            "x": 774,
                            "y": 374
                        },
                        {
                            "x": 6,
                            "y": 373
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
```

Kindly Help

Comment: I think you should use a sample pan card image or obscure the information to protect the privacy of Mr. Pramod Kumar Mahto

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using Node.js. I did it using Node.js using the Microsoft's Computer Vision API. After you get the JSON string, parse that into a JSON object and run a loop to extract data from it. After that use the split function to get the data stored into arrays.

```
//Load the request module
var request = require('request');

var str="";
//Lets configure and request
request({
    url: 'https://api.projectoxford.ai/vision/v1.0/ocr?', //URL to hit
    qs: {"language": "unk",
         "detectOrientation ": "true"
         }, //Query string data

    method: 'POST', //Specify the method

    headers: { //We can define headers too
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key':'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    },

    body: "{'url':'LINK TO THE IMAGE'}",

}, function(error, response, body){
    if(error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        var jsonObj = JSON.parse(body);

        var ob = jsonObj;
            for(i=0;i<ob.regions.length;i++){
                for(j=0;j<ob.regions[i].lines.length;j++){
                    for(k=0;k<ob.regions[i].lines[j].words.length;k++){
                            var str = str + " "+ob.regions[i].lines[j].words[k].text;
                    }
                    str = str + "\n";
                }
            }


            var arr = str.split("\n");

            console.log("Name: " + arr[1]);
            console.log("Father's Name: " + arr[2]);
            console.log("Date of Birth: " + arr[3]);
            console.log("Permanent Account Number: " + arr[5]);

    }
});
```

Just use your own Microsoft Computer Vision API Subscription Key in this. If you want to use your own JSON file generated from your Google Vision API, just scratch off the upper code and use the algorithm at the lower part of the code. It will work! :) Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Based on the sample you provided we can assume that 
1. DEPARTMENT and Signature are going to be available for us in all the responses
2. All the information you need is on separate lines

Based on these assumptions:

```js
const regExpression = new Regex(' /(DEPARTMENT\\n(.*)\\nSignature)/');
const str = response.responses[0].textAnnotations[0].description; // this will be from the api response form vision
const match = str.match(regExpression)[2].split(“\\n”);

/* Output of above script will be like below
[
  "MAHENDRAKUMARRBAGUL",
  "RAMKRISHNA NATTHU BAGUL",
  "01/06/1981",
  "4Permanent Account Number",
  "ANSAB4834E"
]
*/
```